# find lines existing in one file and not in another, based on a portion of the line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have two files *A.dat* and *B.dat*.

A.dat

```
112381550RSAP002839002C00000000020200600000110102020-05-26
112539961RSAP002839002C00000000020200700000140102020-05-26
140823748RSAP002839002C00000000020210200000050102020-05-26
110604754RSAP002839002C00000000020200600000110102020-05-26
```

B.dat

```
112381550RSAP002839002C00000000020200600000000102020-05-26
112539961RSAP002839002C00000000020200700000000102020-05-26
119A06559RSAP002839002C00000000020210100000000102020-05-26
119231672RSAP002839002C00000000020200900000000102020-05-26
118372226RSAP002839002C00000000020200800000000102020-05-26
```

I want to find records in *B.dat* that do not exist in *A.dat* based on the first 22 characters (in **BOLD**)
the output should be below

```
119A06559RSAP002839002C00000000020210100000000102020-05-26
119231672RSAP002839002C00000000020200900000000102020-05-26
118372226RSAP002839002C00000000020200800000000102020-05-26
```

Tried using `grep` like below

```
grep -Fvxf B.dat A.dat > c.dat
```

But didn't find a way to compare only that portion of the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I tried to wrap your samples in code tags bit not sure of they look fine or not, so better to do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS for better understanding. Thank you for adding your efforts in your question.

Comment: I would use the following method based on `awk`: `awk '{s=substr($0,1,22)}(FNR==NR){a[s];next}!(s in a)' A.dat B.dat`

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try the following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{array[substr($0,1,22)];next} !(substr($0,1,22) in array)'  A.dat B.dat
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR then do following.
  array[substr($0,1,22)]          ##Creating an array whose index is first 22 elements of current line.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!(substr($0,1,22) in array)       ##Checking condition if current line first 22 characters are NOT in array the print the current line.
'  A.dat B.dat                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following method based on `awk`:

```
awk '{s=substr($0,1,22)}(FNR==NR){a[s];next}!(s in a)' A.dat B.dat
```

This ensures that you will always match the first 22 characters.

It essentially does the following: everytime a line is read (disregarding the file) it creates a little string `s` containing the first 22 characters of the line. If we process the first file `(FNR==NR)` store the string in an array `a`, if we process the second file, check if that string is a member of `a` and if not, print the line.

You could also attempt a `grep` based solution, but this could lead to false positives, depending on how you like your input:

```
cut -c1-22 A.dat | grep -vFf - B.dat
```

This however could match the first 22 characters of the lines of `A.dat` anywhere in the lines of `B.dat` (not necessarily the first 22 characters)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just grep and colrm as follows (a filename of "-" is understood as stdin and you can use that with "-f"):

```
colrm 23 < A.dat | grep -F -v -f - B.dat
```

If you're not 100% sure those 22-character patterns are going to match only at the starts of lines, you need to add a '^' to each line of output from colrm and elide the "-F" flag from grep's flags, like so:

```
colrm 23 < A.dat | sed -e 's/^/\^/;' | grep -v -f - B.dat
```

Comment: This might fail if any of the first 22 characters contain special regex patterns such as `.*?[]&`

Comment: The second command could fail if there are magic characters in the first 22 characters of a line, yes.  The first one still works but has the noted caveat.  I didn't try to protect against magic characters because it didn't look like a problem with the example data.  Thanks for noting it, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the output is unimportant, here's a `grep`-free method using `bash`, `sort`, and *GNU* `uniq`:

```
sort {A,A,B}.dat | uniq -uw 22
```

...or in *POSIX* shell:

```
sort A.dat A.dat B.dat | uniq -uw 22
```

Output of either method:

```
118372226RSAP002839002C00000000020200800000000102020-05-26
119231672RSAP002839002C00000000020200900000000102020-05-26
119A06559RSAP002839002C00000000020210100000000102020-05-26
```

Comment: This is very inventive! Be aware that POSIX does not support the `-w` flag for `uniq` (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html#tag_20_144)

Comment: Note: if *A.dat* is very large, consecutively reading it twice with `cat A.dat A.dat` could be expensive, in which case  it would be more efficient to something that uses a single pass like: `sed p A.dat | cat - B.dat | sort | uniq -uw 22`.

Comment: You can also just do `sort {A,A,B}.dat | uniq -uw 22` or if you don't want to read the second file twice: `sed p A.dat | sort - B.dat | uniq -uw 22`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks.  Prior to posting, I remember trying `sort` without `cat` and it didn't work for some reason, (I think I might have used `sort -u`),  but on review obviously it does.